# Did I compromise my floor framing by drilling diagonally through a joist?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, foundation, joists

I’m boring some holes to run new wiring and there happened to be two adjacent floor joists under where I was drilling, so I drilled diagonally-vertically through one of the joists. The hole is 3/4” thick. Is this hole a code violation? Did I just compromise the integrity of my foundation?

Pictures below of the hole in question:
[image: the hole in question]
[image: underside of joists]

Comment: Where in the span are you?  Center, or near an end?

Comment: Center. There’s maybe 6 or 7 feet on either side.

Comment: It would be nice to know what the joists are carrying before we declare it safe or over stressed. Can you tell us if it’s a bearing wall or any posts resting on these joists? Someone has carefully spaced the two joists apart so your plumbing can be run up to a wall...which shows you they didn’t want the joists cut/ drilled.

Comment: Foundation? No. Joists? Possibly.

Comment: where does the hole exit?   take some more pictures.

Comment: The pipe in the picture is an old gas line for a radiator. The hole exits inside a wall that runs perpendicular to the joists. The hole is close to a small bathroom with cast iron pipes.

Comment: The photos are not clear as to where the hole is located.  If the joist is compromised, the fix is relatively simple.  You can sister the joist with an appropriately sized piece of lumber, some double-wide joist hangers, and a handful of nails/screws.

Comment: The crawlspace can only be accessed through a ~3x3’ hole in the floor, so I can’t take a full sized piece of lumber down. I could bring down some kind of flitch plate, though, and secure that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called a local engineer and he said that it was sufficient to fill the hole with epoxy putty. I mentioned screwing in some straps around the hole and he said that’s great but not necessary in this case.